# Killing Windows Apps notifications

Tags: windows, windows-store

What is the Windows process that sends notifications from Store apps to the user on the bottom right corner? I cannot find the corresponding apps in task manager so I assume that there is a single centralized process responsible for sending out notifications to the screen. I want to kill this process, because some Store apps do not have the option to disable notifications, and uninstalling the app would seem overkill. What is the name of this process/service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to kill this process, because some Store apps do not have the
>   option to disable notifications, and uninstalling the app would seem
>   overkill.

You just have to disable the notification for the application in question within the `Action center`. You will need to right click on the notification, you want to disable, and select `Turn off notifications for this app`.  Once the notifications for the application have been disabled, you won't receive notifications, for the application in question.

> [image]

[How To Disable App Notifications in Windows 10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-app-notifications-windows-10)

> What is the Windows process that sends notifications from Store apps
>   to the user on the bottom right corner? I cannot find the
>   corresponding apps in task manager so I assume that there is a single
>   centralized process responsible for sending out notifications to the
>   screen.

You would have to kill the Action Center itself which means you would not receive any notifications for any application.  Since disabling Action Center would basically break Windows, you can also kill notifications, through the Settings application instead.

> 1. Open the Settings app.  To do so, either click the Settings icon in the Start menu or use Windows logo and I hotkey.
> 2. In the Settings app, click System, and then click Notifications and actions.
> 3. First, in the Notifications section, make sure that Get notifications from apps and other senders option is turned on. If you
>      turn off this option, notifications for all apps will be disabled.
>      Since we want to disable notifications for specific apps only, it’s
>      important to keep the option turned on.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Now, in the Get notifications from these senders section, turn off the option next to apps that you don’t want to see notifications for.
>      For instance, if you don’t want to see notifications (all kind of
>      notifications) for the Mail app, turn off the option next to it. 
>      Again, don’t turn off this option if you want to disable only desktop
>      notifications and want to see notifications for the app in the Action
>      Center. To turn off only desktop notifications and see notification in
>      the Action Center for the app, click on the app in the list to see
>      more notification actions. Here, turn off **Notification banners**
>      option only.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

[Disable Desktop Notifications For Specific Apps In Windows 10](http://www.intowindows.com/disable-desktop-notifications-for-specific-apps-in-windows-10/)